# Youtube action search intent does not seem to work when the YouTube app is already running

Tags: java, android, youtube

In my Android application, I have a list of YouTube search queries that can be clicked on like this:

```
query1 [button]
query2 [button]
query3 [button]
```

Whenever the user clicks on one such button, the following code is run:

```java
private void sendSearchOnYoutubeIntent(String query){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
    intent.putExtra("query", query);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

When clicking on e.g. `query1`, the YouTube application starts and correctly searches for `query1`. If I then navigate back to my app and click on `query2`, the YouTube application is brought back to the foreground, but will still display the search for `query1`. Only if I manually close the YouTube application and then press on `query2`, the search is executed correctly.

Why is this happening? Can I somehow fix this from my part, or is that a problem with the YouTube app itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` everything else is fine.

```
private void sendSearchOnYoutubeIntent(String query){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
        intent.putExtra("query", query);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```